# Shipping cost is not up-to-date on the order_information page. Checkout page displays shipping properly

Tags: views, commerce, hooks

It's a Drupal 8 Commerce site, and we just changed the shipping rate from 2,90 to 3,5€

Although the shipping rate appears just fine on the checkout/####/review page, On the checkout/####/order_information page appears the old shipping title and rate. The calculation on the cart is just fine. The wording is off though.

Let me share 2 pictures of the phenomenon. Here is the /review page:
[image: Review Page]

and here is the order information page:
[image: Information page]

I can't for the life of me figure out where it gets the old price and renders it in the Information page.

Please note that if you load the page, at first it seems that it will display a radio button with the proper shipping method cost but when the page finally completes loading, it reverts to the 2,90€ price that I so want to replace.

Any idea what might be causing this behaviour and how to fix it?

Here is the page: https://gk-handmade-jewels.gr/ You can make a test order and see what I am trying to describe.

Comment: This looks like a fairly customized checkout flow. It's possible it's coming from custom code on the site and not from your shipping method configurations, or perhaps it's been cached somewhere and simply needs to be cleared. I don't think anyone will be able to quickly answer this for you via this forum.

Comment: Riiight... But I'm lost with all this "Drupal way". I want to start digging but can't figure out where to start. Is there something like a guide of he file structure I could peek to start opening files and unravel this issue?
I mean... how does one add custom code to the site? If maybe I could find that...

Comment: Sorry, this would be a site configuration issue (which would be exported to .yml files in your config directory) or else a custom coding issue contained in either a theme or module. Those are typically in your docroot's themes/custom or modules/custom subdirectory, but it really depends on who built it. Unfortunately, every Drupal site really should be treated as unique unless it's being managed by the same person, but even one person may maintain sites in different ways.